# Analysis (increasing and decreasing function)JAM 2017

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

Here's what i thought- Since the derivative is strictly increasing therefore the 2nd derivative of original function phi must be strictly greater than 0. And 1 is a critical point so it is point of minima.

But i can't figure out the behavior of function in interval 
 [2 3].

Comment: $\varphi''$ need not be greater than $0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi'(1)=0$ and $\phi' $ strictly increasing imply that $\phi'(x) >0$ for all $x >1$ hence for all $x \in [2,3]$. This implies that $\phi$ itself is strictly increasing so its minimum is attained at $x=2$ and maximum at $x=3$. So (A) is true and (B),(C),(D) are all false.